# How can I make sure a user either inserted a description or file before form submission?

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have a foreach row that displays the "message icon" (i dont think it has anything to do with the form since the form is outside the loop:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11xxJ.png)
which displays a chat form that you can either type a chat or send an attachment: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivph8.png)

How can i make one of them required before submission? I tried through multiple JQuery ways but because they are in a for loop and each of them do not have a special id, its not working. any help please? I just need it to show an alert

Here is my code for the form:

```
                <form  method="post"action="<?php echo base_url();?>form_support_chat" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="ticket-reply-form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="chat-left">
                        <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Type Message ..." class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cst_id" value="<?php echo $cst_id; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="arch_ticket" value="<?php echo $arch_ticket; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="ticket_number" value="<?php echo $ticket_number?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="chat-right">
                    <label>  
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assest/icon-img/paperclip.png" class="ic_img" >
                        <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" style="display:none;" id="hidden_upload_file_chatting">
                    </label>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-flat" name="reply" value="reply" >Reply</button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-left: 10px !important;">Close</button>
                    <span id="_showName"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use html5's required value

```
<input  name="cst_id" value="<?php echo $cst_id; ?>" required>
```

or

```
<input  name="cst_id" value="<?php echo $cst_id; ?>" required="true">
```

**update**

Using jQuery, add id value to each input

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if( $('#input1').valid() || $('#input2').valid();  ):

console.log("Success");
endif;
});
```

Comment: i want them to be able to add a file only as well if they want to. So they either have to write in the input field or send a file, but at least one of them.